# I have a set of size n and will randomly select k elements from it...

Tags: probability, combinatorics

A) What is the probability that three specific elements (say x, y, z) are all selected?

B) If S is a subset with size j of the original set, with j less than k, what is the probability that no elements in S are selected?

My attempt for A:

number of ways to select the k elements (disregarding order) = n! / (k!*(n-k)!)

(number of sets that include each of x, y, z) = (# of ways to select k-3 elements from a set of size n-3) = (n-3)! / ((k-3)!*((n-3)-(k-3))!)

And the probability is just the second expression divided by the first expression.

My attempt for B:
number of sets that don't include any elements from S = # of ways to choose k elements from n-j elements = (n-j)! / (k!*((n-j)-k)!)

And so the probability is just that expression divided by the first expression from part A).

I'm not sure if my logic is correct here, so I'd like to know if this method will give the right answer, and I'd also be interested to see different ways to solve the problem (this is the only method I could easily come up with).

Comment: It's bad practice to ask multiple questions in a single post. You should instead focus on a single question, and if needed, ask the other one in a separate post.

Comment: Good reasoning.  All checks out to me!

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.